# Cycles render is rendering everything transparent

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

Cycles renders everything as the transparent checkerboard in both the viewport and the rendered image.
it renders the first time you activate cycles but when you move the camera or anything it freezes the rendered image and everything turns transparent. As shown below with the cube it has a ghost like effect.

I'm using 2.83.5 it also doesn't work on GPU rendering CPU or experimental all my drivers are up to date i have tested this in new documents, on new projects and there were lights in the scene to provide shading. but it still looks like the image below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What GPU (integrated and dedicated) are you using? Have you checked that they fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.83?

Comment: im using 2x RTX 2080 ti

Comment: Does Blender recognize the GPUs in the preferences?

Comment: i edited my post and it seems to recognize everything if this is not what you meant then i dont know

Comment: I would suggest you follow [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685/74827) and create a bug report if the issues isn't resolved by one of the steps outlined there.

Comment: thanks i will report it today, sorry for causing you any issues this community is very lucky to have people like yourself who help others :D

Comment: You're very welcome!